# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. in magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2.4.3

> [2022-05-16 04:11:04] main.CRITICAL: Error: Cannot instantiate
> interface Magento\Framework\Acl\LoaderInterface in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\magento243\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php:50

**when i am install new magento and open backend & fronted.**

Comment: Disable any third-party/custom modules, and try again.

Comment: thanks  you it work ..